# VB.NET debug error: "The current project settings specify that the project will be debugged..."

Tags: vb.net

It seems I've inadvertently converted a VB.NET 2012 project to the type "Publish Online". I was exploring the IDE and started the Publish Wizard, but then cancelled it without doing anything. The VB project does have command line arguments defined in the properties, and the error seems related to that.

How do I revert the project back to "normal mode" from "publish online"...?

The error occurs whenever debugging is started (F5), as follows:

> The current project settings specify that the project will be debugged
> with specific security permissions.  In this mode, command line
> arguments will not be passed to the executable.  Do you want to
> continue debugging anyway?  Yes/No.

[image]

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Go to the Project properties → Security, and then uncheck "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings". Now it debugs and runs without the error.

Comment: Thanks. I inadvertently changed something with some keyboard shortcut sequence in a project/solution, and this fixed it.

Comment: Or... you installed ClickOnce Publishing Tools and it added the setting. Pretty annoying really... this should NOT be a default setting IMHO.